# Is it possible to call a function defined in the java code from renderscript?

Tags: android, gpu, renderscript

I'm creating a face recognition android app and to increase the performance I'm thinking of making use of the phone's GPU using renderscript. I went through some examples which I could find online, and that raised a doubt in my mind. Currently, for my app, I'm making use of an OpenCv function. Now, can I use this predefined function in the renderscript code or do I have to recreate it myself? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

RS doesn't have external linkage, so you can't call arbitrary C functions from RS; you'd have to reimplement it in RS.